# What's the actual formula for resolution in DAC. I found 2 different formula

Tags: dac

Vr/2^n-1 or Vr/2^n which one we're supposed to use and when

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make it meaningfully answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is 2^n -1.

But when n becomes high like say for example n = 10.

2^n -1 and 2^n don't make much difference in calculation.

Eg: for Vref=5,

5/1023 = 0.004887

5/1024 = 0.004883

For ease of calculation, some people just put 2^n

Comment: \\$bawesdxfcgvykurgedzs\\$ => \$bawesdxfcgvykurgedzs\$

Answer (score 1):

\$2^n\$ is the number of discrete values an ADC can have.

However, since you start at zero you have one less non-zero value than you have steps. As such

\$Vr/(2^n-1)\$ is your step size.

Example:

Lets make n = 2 and Vr = 1V

Your first formula \$Vr/(2^n)\$ returns 1/2V, however, your ADC steps values are actually 0, .333, .666 and 1

The second formula \$Vr/(2^n-1)\$ returns \$Vr/3\$ which is indeed 0.333.

Comment: Perhaps it is also useful to mention that when a dataconvertor goes from -vref to +vref, its step size is 2^(n-1)

Comment: Can resolution be also defined as weight of lsb?

Comment: @PrabhanshuDubey the ADC value of 1 is the step size yes.